# How should I call and pass parameter this method?

Tags: c#

How can I call and pass parameter to this method ?

```
public AcceptDocumentResponseType AcceptDocument(
    [XmlElementAttribute("AcceptDocument", Namespace="....")]
    AcceptDocumentType AcceptDocument1) 
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke("AcceptDocument", new object[] {
        AcceptDocument1});
    return ((AcceptDocumentResponseType)(results[0]));
}
```

.... 
I am trying like this but get error: ) expected

```
                AcceptDocumentType adt = new AcceptDocumentType();
                adt.Document = ct;

                Service.Gateway gs = new Gateway();

                AcceptDocumentResult = gs.AcceptDocument(AcceptDocumentType adt); <-- error
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you get errors? What were the errors?

Comment: Sorry, I completed the example

Comment: The method is recursive, right? It looks like you're producing an infinite loop with this method.

Comment: When you call a method the type shouldn't be there. So the line `gs.AcceptDocument(AcceptDocumentType adt)` should be `gs.AcceptDocument(adt)`.

Comment: This code is assigning an object (of type `AcceptDocumentResponseType`) to an array of objects: `object[] results = this.Invoke("AcceptDocument", ...);`.

Comment: Yes in method AcceptDocument is bug... it should be ...AcceptDocumentResponseType[]... instead ...AcceptDocumentResponseType... That was generated from wsdl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a method the type shouldn't be there. So the line:

```
AcceptDocumentResult = gs.AcceptDocument(AcceptDocumentType adt);
```

...should be:

```
AcceptDocumentResult = gs.AcceptDocument(adt);
```

That's why you're getting a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

An initial look would indicate that the issue is with the syntax of the line

```
 AcceptDocumentResult = gs.AcceptDocument(AcceptDocumentType adt);
```

Specifically why do you have the type declaration `AcceptDocumentType` in front of the variable `adt`?

Did you mean to cast it like this?

```
AcceptDocumentResult = gs.AcceptDocument((AcceptDocumentType) adt);
```